# ASP.NET Application Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 Application (ReadyDesk) setup as an Application in IIS.

**The bindings are pointing to**: readydeskdev.domain.com 
**The location of the Application is**: C:/inetpub/wwwwroot/ReadyDesk

On the server, I can successfully go to: readydeskdev.domain.com/ReadyDesk/HD/
However, on another computer, **not on the server**, I cannot hit that Application (URL).
I get a **"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"** error.

The strange thing is I can get to an HTML file or CSS file: 
readydeskdev.domain.com/ReadyDesk/HD/test.htm 

But not any ASPX file, JS file, or image:
readydeskdev.domain.com/ReadyDesk/HD/Default.aspx

**One more thing...**
If I view the URL in Firefox externally, it works just fine.  This seems to be an issue with Internet Explorer. I have never come across this. Can anyone please help me as I am stumped!

**Edit**: I am using IIS7

Comment: Did you check your firewall rules on the client, server and the network between them?

Comment: Yes, we checked all firewall settings.

Comment: Have you checked your proxy settings?

Comment: @KazR, we have done that as well. Does it matter if it is a virtual server or not? Could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's an unusual one.

Double check that IE hasn't cached the error page (F5 to reload without the cache, I think)

You can also hit F12 for the IE developer tools which might shed some light on what kind of error you are getting (a 404, a 500 etc).

Amend the web.config to show errors (the debug=true and RemoteErrors=On (I think)

and maybe hit the endpoint with Fiddler. What does Fiddler say?

Request the endpoint [readydeskdev.domain.com/ReadyDesk/HD/Default.aspx] from another site (like the [WC3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)) - to get an 'external' view of what is going on (and to check the site validates!)

Hope this helps,
Neil

Comment: Thanks, Neil.  I didn't think about the WC3 Validator, but then again, it is a subdomain that can only be accessed internally. I'll check it out with Fiddler, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Using Fiddler, I got the following error:  `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.` and the response header is: `HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure`

Comment: It's not just IE then - which makes a bit more sense. Is the correct version of .NET (2.x) set up in IIS? How about permissions (IIS_IUSRS and so on). I'm pretty sure it's your server setup that's the issue, not the browser.

Comment: It is just IE, that's the issue. With Fiddler open, I hit the URL with Internet Explorer and got the above error.  When I closed Internet Explorer and viewed Fiddler when I hit the URL in Firefox, the response header was `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`